# How to wget https domain when using proxies

Tags: proxy, wget

I am trying to fetch a google(https) page using wget along with proxy

but the below command gives 403 forbidden response

```
wget -T10 --tries=1 -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=https://xxx:xxx https://www.google.com/search?q=JD%20Sports
```

Response

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2016-06-08 21:17:22 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

How to make this command work

i want response as 200 ok and download that web page??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that you're specifying the http_proxy argument, but passing in an https proxy, if instead specify it as a https proxy like

```
https_proxy=https://xxx:xxx
```

Then you should be able to retrieve it. There also could be problems with the configuration of the proxy you're using, but that's out of your control.